# Byte shift inverse operation

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this code

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{-33,-4,20,30};
System.err.println(Arrays.toString(b));

int x =  (b[0] << 24) + (b[1] << 16) + (b[2] << 8) + b[3];

b = new byte[]{(byte)(x >> 24), (byte)(x >> 16), (byte)(x >> 8), (byte)(x)};

System.err.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Output:

```
[-33, -4, 20, 30]
[-34, -4, 20, 30]
```

I cannot figure out why this operations are not invers.

Comment: Is it possible that there is data loss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is unwanted sign extension.

Specifically, `b[1]` is `-4`, or `0xfc` which is sign-extended to `0xfffffffc` then left-shifted to `0xfffc0000`. This has the effect of decrementing the most-significant byte by 1.

Try:

```
int x =  ((b[0] & 0xff) << 24) +
         ((b[1] & 0xff) << 16) +
         ((b[2] & 0xff) << 8) +
          (b[3] & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please disregard my previous answer; it's totally wrong.

I think that the problem here is that when you compose the bits in this manner:

```
(b[0] << 24) + (b[1] << 16) + (b[2] << 8) + b[3]
```

You are *not* doing what you think you're doing.  In particular, suppose that `b[1]` is negative (which it is).  When Java does bitshifts, it always promotes the value to an `int` before doing the shift.  This means that `b[1]` will look like this when it gets promoted:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 bbbbbbbb
```

Here, the leading 1s are from the signed two's-complement representation of integers, which makes negative numbers represented by a lot of leading zeros.  When you shift this number up, you get

```
11111111 bbbbbbbb 00000000 00000000
```

If you then add these bits to `(b[0] << 24)`, which has the form

```
aaaaaaaa 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

You do *not* get

```
aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb 00000000 00000000
```

Because of the leading 1s in the representation.  To fix this, you need to mask out the sign bits before doing the addition.  Specifically, if you change

```
b[1] << 16
```

to

```
(b[1] << 16) & 0x00FFFFFF
```

Then you mask out the bits to get

```
00000000 bbbbbbbb 00000000 00000000
```

So now when you add the two values, you get

```
aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb 00000000 00000000
```

As desired.

The correct expression for composing bits is thus formed by ANDing in the appropriate masks at the appropriate times:

```
(b[0] << 24) + ((b[1] << 16) & 0x00FFFFFF) + ((b[2] << 8) & 0x0000FFFF) + (b[3] & 0x000000FF)
```

I've tested this on my system and it seems to work just fine.

Hope this helps!