# Inverse of left shift by 1

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have the below equation.

```
A=B<<1.
```

Could some one please tell me how I can get back B given A?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The highest bit of B is lost, and there is no way you can get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the right shift operator:

B = A >> 1

Details see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

and this

[Byte shift inverse operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331743/byte-shift-inverse-operation)

Comment: Only if previous operation did not overflow.